# Question about Autosomal Recessive Alleles

Tags: genetics, dna, homework, chromosome

I had a homework question that I could not figure out.

It states:

> A woman has cystic fibrosis in her family and did not want to have a
>   child that suffered from the disease. She and her spouse went for
>   genetic testing and counselling. She tested positive as a carrier and
>   her spouse tested negative, and their first child was born with cystic
>   fibrosis. Explain how this could happen.

This doesn't make sense because the punnet square would be:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  & A  & A  \\
\hline
A & AA & AA \\
\hline
a & Aa & Aa  
\end{array}
$$

This says there are no two recessive alleles which can cause  cystic fibrosis.

Comment: Well, if the question is perfectly correct, than as per my opinion the only alternative left is MUTATION.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I asked my Biology teacher and she said that the if the father is not a carrier, he must have the disease. So the father is aa.

Comment: You should tell your teacher that's a terribly worded question then - "negative" definitely doesn't mean they have the disease! Not your error at all.

Comment: The question came from the book we use, and she also said it was a bad question.

Comment: Well, this answer does not answer your question! It answers it assuming that the real meaning of the question was different than what was actually written! So, I am not quite sure this should be accepted as an answer and not flagged, although I agree that most likely your textbook did not expect you to perform probabilistic calculations and it actually was a very simple terribly poorly written question.

Comment: I copied the question right out of the book, and its only Grade 11 Biology. We didn't learn any calculations.

Answer (score 9):

If really cystic fibrose is expressed only in homozygotes, then here are some possible explanations:

- Mutation

  - very improbable
- Autofecundation

  - very improbable
- False Negative when testing the father

  - Because of the test False Negative Rate. @kmm made a very interesting comment below. He said that according to [this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2014829) 75% of the mutations coding for disease correspond to one pattern (3 base pair deletion). The other 25% of the mutations coding for disease might not be detected in the standard test. If so, it is very likely that a the test conducting on the father was a false negative. It would be worth further investigate the test that are usually performed to confirm this.
  - Because of human error. The laboratory operator might accidentally switch two samples or accidentally introduce stranger DNA before PCR (assuming the test is performed through sequencing)
  - I have no idea concerning the probability for such thing to occur!
- trisomy

  - The assumes that a trisomic that have two recessive allele coding for disease and on dominant allele coding for health yield to a individual expressing the disease!
  - The gene for cystic fibrose is on chromosom 7. Trisomy 7 is extremely rare if I'm not mistaken.
- The father is not the father!

  - According to different studies between 5% and 20% of the people are not fathered by the man they think is their dad.
  - According to [this source](http://www.cfmedicine.com/htmldocs/CFText/genetics.htm) the frequency of the disease is 1/2500 in UK. Assuming Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium the frequency of the allele coding for disease should be $p=0.02$.
  - The probability that the baby comes from another man and that the baby express the disease is $$a \cdot \left(\frac{2\cdot p\cdot (1-p)}{4} + \frac{p^2}{2}\right)$$, where $a$ is the probability that the baby was fathered by another man (let's say 10%) and $p$ is the frequency of the allele coding for the disease (0.02). The division by 2 and 4 are due to the probability that the (real) father and the mother transmit both the alleles coding for the disease.  This probability equals $$0.1 \cdot \left(\frac{2\cdot 0.2\cdot (1-0.2)}{4} + \frac{0.2^2}{2}\right) = 0.01$$ This seems to be from far the most likely explanation! Note: this assumes that the mother is heterozygote (does not express the disease) otherwise, the probability would be 0.02.

Comment: I would also add "human error" to the list, a person changing the outcome, e.g. by contaminating the sample or a spelling error while transcribing the result. This might be surprisingly likely - somebody overly tired, or having a bad day.

Comment: Yes, I kinda incorporated "human error" within the False Negative point. I'll make it more clear

Comment: It's probably the false negatives. According to http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2014829, 75% of carriers have the standard pattern. They are probably not routinely testing the other 25% (which might constitute lots of different patterns).